# Vertical center text which overflows at bottom only

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to center text in a container `div`, such that when it overflows it only overflows on the bottom.

A single line of text would be centered:

```
------------------------
|                      |
|A line of text        |
|                      |
------------------------
```

Two or three lines of text (as many as needed to fill the container) would also be centered.

```
------------------------
|A line of text        |
|A line of text        |
|A line of text        |
------------------------
```

But when there is too much text for the container, it would start overflowing at the bottom (eventually being hidden by CSS).

```
------------------------
|A line of text        |
|A line of text        |
|A line of text        |
------------------------
A line of overflown text
A line of overflown text
```

How can this be achieved with CSS?

---

NOT a duplicate of:

- stackoverflow.com/q/15680785/3597276 (in my case, I need the text to be centered vertically when it fits the container)

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: Have you tried overflow-y CSS property?

Comment: So far I've tried flexbox (managed to center the text, but it overflows top and bottom). I am currently using display:table-cell, but with this I cannot use the overflow property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```css
.parent {
  margin: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.child {
  max-height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Line of text
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Line of text<br>
    Line of text<br>
  </div>  
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Line of text<br>
    Line of text<br>
    Line of text<br>
    Line of text<br>
    Line of text<br>
    Line of text<br>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Adding to this, you could play with line-height in css to try and get the text to overflow nicely, but you'd need a high value is you have bottom padding to your container. There is no simple way to create a bigger margin between the last line in the box and the first line outside the box.

Comment: @s1h4d0w Don't understand how that relates to my answer of the question. Also, when dealing with text and font, there will be no way make a text do that nicely cross browser (unless start fiddling with script, which still will be difficult).

Comment: @LGSon great answer! That's exactly the behavior I want.

Comment: @LGSon True, but still valid. I wasn't saying your answer was incomplete, just adding a bit of information. Either if he's just trying to make it overflow and then hide it, or actually wants it to visibly overflow it's useful to know. If you're working with pixel values for the line-height it should be pretty accurate. Different fonts should not affect the line-height.